# What are the best books in defense of Platonism in Philosophy of Mathematics?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

I am interested in the subject and was recently doing some research about literature to read about it, but it seems that there aren’t many books on the topic. Some suggestions for books in defense of Platonism would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "best" is hard to say.. but can be a good starting point: Marco Panza & Andrea Sereni, [Plato’s Problem An Introduction to Mathematical Platonism (Palgrave, 2013)](https://books.google.it/books?id=4Zq3DchGVR4C&printsec=frontcover). See also: James Robert Brown, [Platonism Naturalism and Mathematical Knowledge (Routledge, 2011)](https://books.google.it/books?id=K0LmD3MnnjYC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Thanks. Do you any more books on the topic?

Comment: For modern versions of platonism (in the weak sense of some sort of realism about mathematical objects) see [Balaguer, Platonism and Anti-Platonism in Mathematics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Platonism_and_Anti_Platonism_in_Mathemat.html?id=hbGhsAJIdEQC), [Hale-Wright, The Reason’s Proper Study](https://books.google.com/books?id=X4btafC6dskC&printsec=front_cover), and [Colyvan, The Indispensability of Mathematics](http://www.colyvan.com/book.html).